# Flask: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following this popular tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYWiDiIUxQc to make a Flask Web App. I am doing this in Visual Code Studio, but I am encountering an error with SQLAlchemy.

```
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

This is my code for importing the module.

I am receiving "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'". I have checked that I have correctly installed flask_sqlalchemy, by entering 'pip list' in CMD, inside my project folder, and it is listed under the installed packages. So I am confused about why VScode is unable to find the module. After searching online a potential problem seems to be with virtual environments, but I seem to have correctly installed the module locally for the project, so I have no idea what the problem is.

After

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure vscode to use your virtualenv.

Click `ctrl+shift+p` and write "python select interpreter", click enter and enter your venv interpreter path

Comment: I'm a little confused about the need for virtualenv. From the tutorial, I can't see any mention of virtualenv, he just seems to use pip in command line locally within the project folder. Does this install modules locally, and if so, why is a virtualenv needed? Also, how do I find my venv interpreter path?

Comment: Virtualenvs were born to solve dependency problems related to multiple installations on the same machine.For example you can install software A with library C v1.2.3 as dependencty on your machine. later have the need to install also software B with dependency of library C v1.3.5 that introduced breaking changes that would break software A. With virtualenvs you isolate the 2 installations environments

Comment: If you installed flask_sqlachemy globally you have to tell vscode what's the global interpreter you're using for that project, it might be set to the wrong version of the interpreter. To get the correct path you can use the command `which python`

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. With regards to installing flask_sqlachemy globally, as I said, the way I installed it was by going into CMD, changing the directory to the folder in which the python file I am working on is located, and then using 'pip install flask_sqlachlemy'. Is this a global install? Also, where should I be using the 'which python' command?

Comment: If you haven't created and activated any venv, running a clean `pip install` installs the package globally.
Are you using Windows, Linux or Mac? `which` command runs on Linux and Mac, but I don't know whats the equivalent on Windows. On Linux and Mac you can run `which` command everywhere on the terminal and it will print the path of the executable passed as argument.
Probably when you run your project from terminal you're using a different python version than vscode default one

Comment: I am using Windows. According to CMD, I am using Python 3.8.3. When selecting Python 3.8.3 as the interpreter path on VSCode, it still does not fix the problem.